# Set focus on dynamically generated components using refs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-ref

I've got to create some dynamic refs in order to set focus on the `Input` that is contained within the custom component.

Currently this is how I'm rendering the elements:

```
const countRow = denom => {
  this[`${denom.id}-ref`] = React.createRef();
  return (
    <CountRow
    ref={this[`${denom.id}-ref`]}
    id={`${denom.name.singular.toLowerCase()}-${denom.id}`}
    tenderValue={denom.value}
    label={denom.denomination.label}
    onChange={(e, value) => this.handleBillsOnChange(e, denom)}
    onEnter={() => this.onEnter(denom)}
  />
}

{itterableArray.map(item => countRow(item)}
```

In my `onEnterFunction` I am trying to move from one `<CountRow />` to the next.

At the end of that function:

```
onEnter = denom => {
  //some stuff that doesn't matter
  this[`${denom.id}-ref`].focus()
}
```

The last line of the `onEnter` function is always blowing up. Saying:
`TypeError: _this["".concat(...)].focus is not a function`

Can someone provide guidance for what I need to do in order to select focus of a specific `<CountRow />`?

Comment: It appears you're missing your closing backtick.

Comment: Sorry that was just SO error, not missing in code. Question edited

Comment: Use `_this["".concat(...)].current.focus`,since `CountRow` is a custom class component rather than an HTML element, `CountRow` should expose a `focus` function property.See https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example

```
const countRow = denom => {
    let ref=React.createRef();
    let onEnter = () => {
        ref.current.focus();
    }
    //setTimeout(onEnter,3000)
    return (
        <CountRow
            ref={ref}
            //   id={`${denom.name.singular.toLowerCase()}-${denom.id}`}
            //   tenderValue={denom.value}
            //   label={denom.denomination.label}
            //   onChange={(e, value) => this.handleBillsOnChange(e, denom)}
            onEnter={onEnter}
        />)
};

class CountRow extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.myRef=React.createRef();
        this.focus=()=>this.myRef.current.focus(); 
    }
    render() {
        return <input type="text" ref={this.myRef}/>
    }
}
```